# How can I delete my Facebook posts from an open group where I'm no longer a member?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

**Background**

Long time ago I have, unfortunately, created an embarrassing Facebook group and later decided to remove it. According to Facebook's instructions, that can be done by removing all members and then removing myself. The group disappeared. Now, after about 4 years, it turns out that four members were deactivating their accounts at the time of the deletion and the group has magically appeared again. Unfortunately, my only association with that group is two (very, very) embarrassing posts and I'm trying to delete them.

**Question**

Is there any way to delete **own** post from an **open group** of which I'm not a member anymore? (Using Facebook UI, Graph API, a contact form, anything, any method)

Comment: I've never tried, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.  But logically my first step would be to re-join the group   (change your settings to not notify anybody about what you do first!), and see if you can just delete the messages?    If you're still using the same Facebook account, then chances are that the posts are still identifed as "yours" at database level.

Comment: @MaryC.fromNZ, the group currently has 4 members, I can only see one (it says there are 4 but I can see their names). The one I see is an Admin, sadly it looks like a fake account (hasn't liked or posted anything in years, no cover photo, no activity at all)

Comment: and I cannot join the group since the new Facebook groups require admin approval (even for open groups)

Comment: That 'Admin' account is probably an old deactivated account, hence the no cover photo, etc. Your best bet is to contact Facebook.

Comment: Are you sure your posts are visible to others? Try the "view your timeline as..." to get to the postings? Otherwise, you could report the group, claiming it's harassing you (admin is inactive, won't re-add you to allow you to delete posts). There's an option in the sequence of screens to "Report to facebook" and the final step allows you to "Receive an email from facebook after the report is handled." (or something like that)

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, I have contacted Facebook regarding this matter 3 times since December 1st, I haven't received any reply regarding my problem. I have, however, received a reply "warning" me about abusing the reporting functionality.

Comment: Another route: ask one of the other members to become the admin and add you to the group so you can delete those posts. If the current admin is defunct, anyone can assume that role. "If you're a member of a group with no admins, you can become an admin by clicking Make Me Admin under Members in the right column." from https://www.facebook.com/help/121869921229278/

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, there are 3 members now in the group (I can only see the number) one of them is the fake/idle admin account. I guess the only solution is in the hands of Facebook's support.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `https://www.facebook.com/USERNAME/allactivity` or click on the activity log on your profile page, and from there you should be able to view all your group posts (you can filter by category of activity), and then you can delete the comment.

Comment: Can you provide documentation or proof of this activity? Answers should be conclusive and not possibles.

Comment: I have already tried that, but when I try to delete it (by clicking the circular icon) I get a [menu that says "nothing"](http://i.imgur.com/oCjl5.png).

Answer (score 1):

1. [Report the issue as a bug](https://www.facebook.com/help/326603310765065/) to Facebook.
2. Ask them to delete the two posts.
3. If that doesn't work, [read this page](https://www.facebook.com/help/221819491164051/) on Facebook's position.

> This is most likely because one of the other admins removed you as an admin. The best thing you can do is reach out to the other admins and ask them to add you back.
>
> Note that there are different kinds of Page admins. Managers can add and remove admins, so be sure you choose your Page managers carefully.

1. File a lawsuit. This could possibly expose what you posted before you make it to court.

Comment: I have reported it two times. First time they ignored me, second time they told me that this is not a bug and this is by design.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to re-join the group momentarily before you can delete the posts. Or maybe the creator of the group has not allowed anyone else controls over the page.

Answer (score 0):

So what you need to do is go to the post and click on edit post and then it will bring up a small page and it will say do you want to delete this post then click delete and you're done.

Comment: Please type whole words. The length limit on posts is 30,000 characters not 140. Using text speak makes your posts hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution guys. use "facebook phone application".. you're welcome you can tip me if you want highly appreciated it. have a nice day/ evening everyone...

1A8v5z4fYrXFR5QBcDjCtMFfJTkQ5RE4wU - Bitcoin